# cannot enable Semantic Highlighting when using Rust Analyzer for VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, rust-analyzer

I am testing whether it's working or not by following [the instructions here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Semantic-Highlighting-Overview#how-can-i-find-out-what-semantic-tokens-are-available-and-how-they-are-themed).

I do not see a "semantic token type" section in the inspector popup.

Furthermore, if I change the color of a very obvious token type (`"variable"`) to something unmistakable like "red",  I do not see any color changes being applied.

I have enabled semantic highlighting both globally, and for the particular theme I am using:

```json
    "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
    "editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Darcula Solid]": {
            "enabled": true,
            "rules": {
                "variable": "#ff0000"
            }
        }
    },
```

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be that `rust-analyzer` was *not* running for the particular project I was in, as it couldn't figure out what `Cargo.toml` was associated with the project. Stopping `rust-analyzer` and restarting it caused it to trigger a pop-up which suggests a possible `Cargo.toml`, which in my case, was sufficient to get `rust-analyzer` working, and then semantic highlighting.